Keycloak returns "Cookie not found"
I am trying to deploy keycloak on a kubernetes cluster and when I am trying to login to admin console it is returning "Cookie not found". Even under application cookie I don't see any cookies. Below is my deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-deployment
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: keycloak:v0.0.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 100m
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 300m
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: KC_DB
          value: postgres
        - name: KC_DB_URL_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: DB_HOST_URL
              name: postgres-config
        - name: KC_DB_URL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: DB_NAME
              name: postgres-config
        - name: KC_DB_URL_PORT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: DB_PORT
              name: postgres-config
        - name: KC_DB_SCHEMA
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: KEYCLOAK_SCHEMA
              name: postgres-config
        - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: DB_PWD
              name: postgres-credentials
        - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: DB_USER
              name: postgres-credentials
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-credentials
              key: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-credentials
              key: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
        - name: image.debug
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

The same deployment I do on minikube and access the service via minikube service keycloak-service --url it is showing cookie and also letting me login to admin console.
I tried most of the solutions provided for similar question
